Flowbite is not working on mobile chrome browser but works on firefox (Works fine on laptop and when checked for reponsiveness)
The hamburg button is not working. When I click on it, sidebar doesn't open. It works on my laptop browser just fine but on mobile its not working. I tried on firefox it works just fine.
github link
deployment
I was using flowbite before instead of flowbite-react. I changed it but still its not working.
